# Confusion on when to use T.let vs. T.cast

Tags: sorbet

Based on: https://sorbet.org/docs/type-assertions

In my mind, `T.cast` seems like a more powerful version of `T.let`. `T.cast(expr, type)` forces Sorbet to accept `expr` as `type`, even if `expr` cannot be statically verified as `type`. `T.let(expr, type)` hints to Sorbet that `expr` has `type`, and Sorbet will be able to typecheck that hint is valid. Based on this understanding, I would assume that `T.cast` could always be used in place of `T.let`, but `T.let` is preferred because Sorbet is providing the most type safety. However, I recently found a case where that is not true (see below).

This example is based on: https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference#7001

```rb
# typed: true

class Main
  extend T::Sig

  sig { params(elem: Integer).returns(T::Boolean) }
  def valid?(elem)
    elem == 0
  end

  sig { params(list: T::Array[Integer]).returns(T::Boolean) }
  def works(list)
    # Declare `all_valid` with type `T::Boolean`
    all_valid = T.let(false, T::Boolean)

    list.each do |elem|
      # Does not change the type of `all_valid`
      all_valid &&= valid?(elem) # ok
    end

    all_valid
  end

  sig { params(list: T::Array[Integer]).returns(T::Boolean) }
  def does_not_work(list)
    all_valid = T.cast(false, T::Boolean)

    list.each do |elem|
      # ERROR! Changing the type of a variable in a loop is not permitted
      all_valid &&= valid?(elem)
    end

    all_valid
  end
end
```

Why does this work with `T.let` but not with `T.cast`?

Answer (score 1):

The `T.let` annotation explicitly widens the type from `FalseClass` to `T:Boolean`

`T.cast` on the other hand simply relaxes Sorbet’s static checks, it doesn’t silence type errors at runtime that occur from treating `TrueClass` or `FalseClass` as `T::Boolean`.